# varnish google analytics Magento speed issue

Tags: magento, google-analytics, varnish

I have setup a standard varnish installation for a Magento webshop on a Cent OS linux server.

When I manual open the page into google chrome I see the page is loaded very speedly. 
See as example:

35 requests  ❘  14.5 KB transferred  ❘  550 ms (load: 804 ms, DOMContentLoaded: 481 ms)

In my Google analytics I see after a week still load times from 2 seconds. Could It be that if Google is visit the webshop that Varnish is not working?

The same is in Google site helper, there I see the site content is bigger than what I see back in my browser by manual download.

Could it be something with the cookie setup?

Comment: Can you give a link to a varnish config?

Comment: Varnish cache pages for a period of time (from several minutes to several hours or days) after that page is deleted from cache. If you do a request to an unchached page it is slow. So if your site has not many visits you will get a lot of cache misses and see such big value in google analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my delayed response. I am already used the Turpentin - Varnish Cache extension.
Below you find my default.vcl

```
C{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
static pthread_mutex_t lrand_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void generate_uuid(char* buf) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&lrand_mutex);
long a = lrand48();
long b = lrand48();
long c = lrand48();
long d = lrand48();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lrand_mutex);
// SID must match this regex for Kount compat /^\w{1,32}$/
sprintf(buf, "frontend=%08lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%08lx",
a,
b & 0xffff,
(b & ((long)0x0fff0000) >> 16) | 0x4000,
(c & 0x0fff) | 0x8000,
(c & (long)0xffff0000) >> 16,
d
);
return;
}
}C
import std;
backend default {
.host = "IPADRESHERE";
.port = "80";
.first_byte_timeout = 1000s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 1000s;
}
backend admin {
.host = "IPADRESHERE";
.port = "80";
.first_byte_timeout = 21600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 21600s;
}
acl crawler_acl {
"127.0.0.1";
}
acl debug_acl {
"92.108.107.170";
"84.85.36.51";
"80.60.79.41";
}
sub generate_session {
if (req.url ~ ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session = regsub(
req.url, ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*", "frontend=\1");
} else {
C{
char uuid_buf [50];
generate_uuid(uuid_buf);
VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_REQ,
"\030X-Varnish-Faked-Session:",
uuid_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
if (req.http.Cookie) {
std.collect(req.http.Cookie);
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; " + req.http.Cookie;
} else {
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
}
}
sub generate_session_expires {
C{
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm now_tm = *gmtime(&now);
now_tm.tm_sec += 86400;
mktime(&now_tm);
char date_buf [50];
strftime(date_buf, sizeof(date_buf)-1, "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z", &now_tm);
VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_RESP,
"\031X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires:",
date_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.restarts == 0) {
if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
} else {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
}
if (!true || req.http.Authorization ||
req.request !~ "^(GET|HEAD)$" ||
req.http.Cookie ~ "varnish_bypass=1") {
return (pipe);
}
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(.*)//+(.*)", "\1/\2");
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
} else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
} else {
unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
}
}
if (req.url ~ "^(/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
set req.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake = "1";
if (req.url ~ "^(/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?admin") {
set req.backend = admin;
return (pipe);
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bcurrency=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Currency = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bcurrency=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bstore=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Store = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bstore=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.url ~ "/turpentine/esi/getBlock/") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = regsub(
req.url, ".*/method/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = regsub(
req.url, ".*/access/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "esi" && req.esi_level == 0 &&
!(false || client.ip ~ debug_acl)) {
error 403 "External ESI requests are not allowed";
}
}
if (req.http.Cookie !~ "frontend=") {
if (client.ip ~ crawler_acl ||
req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") {
set req.http.Cookie = "frontend=crawler-session";
} else {
call generate_session;
}
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
unset req.http.Cookie;
unset req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
return (lookup);
}
if (req.url ~ "^(/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?(?:admin|api|cron\.php)" ||
req.url ~ "\?.*__from_store=") {
return (pipe);
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ "(?:[?&](?:__SID|XDEBUG_PROFILE)(?=[&=]|$))") {
return (pass);
}
if (req.url ~ "[?&](utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)?|&)(?:utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=[^&]+", "\1");
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)&|\?$)", "\1");
}
return (lookup);
}
}
sub vcl_pipe {
unset bereq.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake;
set bereq.http.Connection = "close";
}
sub vcl_hash {
hash_data(req.url);
if (req.http.Host) {
hash_data(req.http.Host);
} else {
hash_data(server.ip);
}
hash_data(req.http.Ssl-Offloaded);
if (req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent) {
hash_data(req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent);
}
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Store || req.http.X-Varnish-Currency) {
hash_data("s=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Store + "&c=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Currency);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
hash_data(regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1"));
}
return (hash);
}
sub vcl_hit {
}
sub vcl_fetch {
set req.grace = 15s;
if (req.url ~ "^(/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
unset beresp.http.Vary;
set beresp.do_gzip = true;
if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
} else {
if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie = beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}
unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
unset beresp.http.Expires;
unset beresp.http.Pragma;
unset beresp.http.Cache;
unset beresp.http.Age;
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi == "1") {
set beresp.do_esi = true;
}
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache == "0") {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
} else {
if (true &&
bereq.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
set beresp.ttl = 28800s;
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=28800";
} elseif (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) {
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Session = regsub(req.http.Cookie,
"^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1");
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" &&
req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "public") {
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=" + regsub(
req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1");
}
set beresp.ttl = std.duration(
regsub(
req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1s"),
300s);
if (beresp.ttl == 0s) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
}
} else {
set beresp.ttl = 3600s;
}
}
}
return (deliver);
}
}
sub vcl_deliver {
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session) {
call generate_session_expires;
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; expires=" + resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires + "; path=/";
if (req.http.Host) {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", "");
}
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie + "; httponly";
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires;
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" && req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private") {
set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-cache";
}
if (false || client.ip ~ debug_acl) {
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Hits = obj.hits;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Currency = req.http.X-Varnish-Currency;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Store = req.http.X-Varnish-Store;
} else {
unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
unset resp.http.Via;
unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
unset resp.http.Server;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Flush-Events;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Block;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Session;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The speed measurement of Google Analytics is not "when Google visitis your website". It is the data from users that visit your website, and how long the website needs to load for them. (Note that the data in this section is not from all visitors, but only a small amount.)
   Several things on the user-side, e.g. browser cache, network speed etc, influence this page load time.
2. Afaik, Turpentine does not cache sessions that don't use a cookie. So, your assumption that the site is slow when Google (crawler) visit(s) it may still be correct. This is, nevertheless, not the data you see in Google Analytics.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
Try installing this extension to magento:
[Turpentine - Varnish Cache](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/2984.html)

One of the things it does is stripping some of the google bot tags making it hit the cache.